# How can I change my admin theme in symfony 1.4?

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony-1.4

I am using sfAdminJrollerTheme Plugin for some parts of my application, but when I generate new modules without admin generator, I lose same look and feel than jroller in my other application pages.  I know maybe is good idea to use admin generator for everything but I cannot change all my modules.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use the admin generator then you have to create your own look and feel using HTML and CSS.

Have a look at the generated files that exist in the cache folder to see the PHP that the admin generator generates.

Comment: Thanks! I got my solution looking for admin auto-generated files in cache folder.  Then I used some of that look and feel in my other apps.

Answer (score 1):

The admin generator is excellent for making simple modules for manging data. Plus they can be built very quickly, but I would not advise using them for *everything*.

Creating a basic module and developing your own custom functionality is much more powerful.